# how to recall a function over and over in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, callback

i want a picture keep fading in and out until infinity with some delay.How can achive that with jquery?I tried like this but it doesn't work.

```
$(document).ready(
setTimeout(
    function () {
        $("#ssio").fadeToggle(1000);
        setTimeout(function(), 2000)
    }, 2000));
```

Thank you:)

Comment: you should use `setInterval` instead of `setTimeout`

Comment: yeah thanks:)didn't know that!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simple:

```
$(document).ready(
setInterval(
    function () {
        $("#ssio").fadeToggle(1000);
    }, 2000));
```

Comment: `clearInterval` is also worth looking for. He could want it to stop sometime in future :)

Comment: yeah thanks!i also came up with a simpler idea myself:)thanks!

Comment: @px5x2: how can i stop it in future?

Comment: @aran `setInterval` returns an id, just pass it to `clearInterval` function and it will stop.

Comment: @px5x2 can you explain more?

Comment: @aran, kike this:
$(document).ready(
var x = setInterval(
    function () {
        $("#ssio").fadeToggle(1000);
    }, 2000));

clearInterval(x);

Comment: @aran `var tid = setInterval(/*blabla*/); clearInterval(tid);`

Answer (score 0):

this way:

```
$(document).ready(
setTimeout(
    function fader() {
        $("#ssio").fadeToggle(1000);
        setTimeout(fader(), 2000);
    }, 2000));
```

Comment: `setTimeout(fader, 2000);` Also, bear in mind that this would not wait for `fadeToggle` to complete!

Comment: @lshettyl:why?toggle takes 1 second while this waits 2!

Comment: @px5x2: can i stop this one using jquery stop() in future?